# VS code faded text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

VS Code is fading a part of my code, like it is not being reached, even though it is. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

simul = []

for i in range(3):

    simul.append(pd.Series(np.arange(3)))

print(3)
simul_2 = pd.concat(simul, axis=0)
print(4)
```

And this is how it's formatted in VS Code:

[image]

As you can see, the line `print(4)` after `simul_2 = pd.concat(simul, axis=0)` is faded. If I comment `simul_2 = pd.concat(simul, axis=0)` then it's back to normal. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When attempting to run the code on my own setup I experience the same issue. Pylance was showing the code as unreachable and thus the line was faded.

I corrected the issue by updating to the latest version.

[image: Code successfully reached]

If you navigate to the extensions tab, search for Pylance, and select preRelease version it should correct your issue.